# How to show a image coming from url on image view?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to show an image which is coming from a url.I have parsed that image and have stored in bitmap. In my testing program its working fine with .

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But when i m doing it in expandable list view it is showing nothing. For your information when i m writing .

```
imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home);
```

its working fine, But i want to show it dynamically.

Comment: What's the code you have done for downloading image from URL and then displaying it in ImageView?

Comment: If you are looking for Asynchronous image loading then here you go: [Android – Asynchronous image loading in ListView](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/)

Comment: I have used asynk task for this purpose.
simply used the httpclient and all and for converting response to bitmaps i have used this code

Comment: BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

Answer (score 0):

You can directly load the image into image-view without saving it through this code

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl("URL PATH"));
```

Or 
for showing the image after saving it.

```
imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable);
```

you can convert the bitmap into drawable.

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
Bitmap bm= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path); 
imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```